# How to calculate differences between maximum value and current value for each row?

Tags: mysql

My sales table looks like this.

```
region          sales
======================
East            1200
Midwest         (Null)
North           2500
South           4000
West            2400
```

Expected query result:

```
region          sales     diff
================================
East            1200      2800
Midwest         0         4000
North           2500      1500
South           4000      0
West            2400      1600
```

The `diff` column is calculated by `max(sales) - sales`. I don't know well about SQL and I even don't know how I can write a search on google. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of MYSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MAX value you get in an subselect, the rest is simple math

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Sales
>     (`region` varchar(7), `sales` varchar(6))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Sales
>     (`region`, `sales`)
> VALUES
>     ('East', '1200'),
>     ('Midwest', '(Null)'),
>     ('North', '2500'),
>     ('South', '4000'),
>     ('West', '2400')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> `region`
> , `sales`
> ,(SELECT MAX(`sales` ) FROM Sales) - `sales` AS diff
> FROM Sales
> ```
>
> ```
> region  | sales  | diff
> :------ | :----- | ---:
> East    | 1200   | 2800
> Midwest | (Null) | 4000
> North   | 2500   | 1500
> South   | 4000   |    0
> West    | 2400   | 1600
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63d2002c8cedaba03188e4f3500845be)*

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 8+, you can use window functions

```
SELECT region
     , COALESCE(sales, 0) as sales
     , MAX(sales) OVER () - COALESCE(sales, 0) as diff
FROM Sales
```